In Svelte, how can I set the height of a span?
In normal HTML and CSS you would do this:
<span>"Hello, World!"</span>

<style>
  span {
    background: yellow; /* to see span dimensions */
    height: 3rem;
  }
</style>

Doing the same thing in a .svelte file doesn't work. Is there a workaround or another way to go about this in Svelte?

display: inline-block?

<span> is an inline-level element, and by default, its height is determined by the height of the content it wraps. Inline elements do not have height or width. you should be using
display: block; 

or
display: inline-block;

